# Copying a pdf using node's fs results in a different file

Tags: node.js, pdf

I have the following code, which I expect to copy a pdf but it doesn't copy it exactly and the file size is off between 286KB vs the original 202KB and the copy does not open in a pdf reader. I tried this on other languages and I get the same issue. I get a similar if not identical result from opening the original pdf as a text file on vs code, copying and pasting the contents into a new file. Thank you!

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./original.pdf', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  fs.writeFile('./copy.pdf', chunk, err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
});
```

EDIT: To clarify, I'm not looking for another approach/library/api, but rather an explanation of why my method does not work and a modification of either the code or the copying and pasting the contents approach. Thank you!

Comment: you are forcing the encoding to "utf8" and pdf's are binary, don't pass the encoding and test

Answer (score 0):

You can use `copyFile` method from `fs/promises`:

```
import { copyFile } from 'fs/promises';
await copyFile('./original.pdf', './copy.pdf');
```

You can read more about it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_copyfile_src_dest_mode).

Comment: thanks. i was looking for a broader explanation on why my code or my manually copying and pasting does not work. I'd like for a modified version of either method rather than use another api. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./original.pdf', (err, data) => {
  fs.writeFile('./copy.pdf', data, err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
});
```

simply delete the encoding from the `readFile`-function and use the variable                 '`data`' from the callback in the `writeFile`-function